# How to move scrollbar(horizontal) pointer to the specific location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a pagination at bottom of a page.after each click on pagination page get refreshed with new data and the clicked number is being highlighted..
the scrollbar is horizontal as shown in below image. 
[scrollbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvreu.jpg)

when i click to last number of pagination, this no gets highlighted but scrollbar thumb not being moved.

this is my code for pagination:

```css
    .pagination::-webkit-scrollbar {
          background-color:#D9D9D9;
          height:5px;
     }

    .pagination::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
               -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #0C62B3;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="pagination">

                    @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.PageCount; i++)
                    {

                        if (i != Model.CurrentPageIndex)
                        {
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:PagerClick(@i);">@i</a></li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                               <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:PagerClick(@i);">@i</a></li>
                        }

                    }

    </ul>
```

I was trying to give hardcoded value to scrollbar:

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
              var navwidth = $('.pagination');
              navwidth.scrollLeft(navwidth.scrollLeft() - 200);
          });
```

but nothing has happened..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the scrollbar is already to the left the function `scrollLeft()` returns 0. If you minus that with 200 you get -200 which wont work. If you add 200 it will work.

Also added a little css and random text to make the list show a horizontal scrollbar when overflowing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navwidth = $('.pagination');
  navwidth.scrollLeft(navwidth.scrollLeft() + 200);
});
```

```css
.pagination {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pagination::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  height: 5px;
}

.pagination::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #0C62B3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:PagerClick(@i);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tincidunt, lorem at cursus condimentum, libero enim scelerisque neque, et placerat magna turpis sed sapien. Phasellus vitae nulla sit amet est malesuada vulputate.</a></li>
  <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:PagerClick(@i);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tincidunt, lorem at cursus condimentum, libero enim scelerisque neque, et placerat magna turpis sed sapien. Phasellus vitae nulla sit amet est malesuada vulputate.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what to do if i want to set scrollbar thumb to extreme right

Comment: @JecobJr. `navwidth.scrollLeft(navwidth.width());` set the value to the width of the element.